# Scraping websites data in structured columns

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** few websites data using selenium. I'm **scraping** it using the standard way like by css, xpath, id, etc, but for every new website I have to write new selenium script by inspecting every websites element.

Now I got a new requirement from client, he wants a **scraper** which will **scrape** data from "any website", no matter what the website html structure is.

And it should get and put the data in columns like, postdate, description, category, location and few other headers like department, region etc

All above headers might not be present for a given website, but **scraper** should get the available data and put that into the respective column in a DB.

And I need to do it without using the selenium standard way, according to me its like a search engine robot who goes to websites and fetch h1 h2 h3 etc..

I am confused how I can achieve this, I am looking for some hint, idea, suggestions etc, to complete my task. I hope my question is valid for SO.

any Programming language will do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using any programming language?

Comment: @SnakeFoot yes python and any other will also do

Comment: @PaulCrovella cut him some slack... he is a new entry.

Comment: @PaulCrovella lolz, thanks for it. I will keep this my status update.

Comment: you should research web crawlers .https://elitedatascience.com/python-web-scraping-libraries and this: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe

Comment: @SnakeFoot thanks brother, I know all about the coding, I want the logic, the idea so that I can achieve my task